# common lisp: looking for a library which works like (str:string-case BUT with regular expessions

Tags: switch-statement, common-lisp

I am trying to rewrite an AWK script in Common Lisp (as a kind of learning exercise)

I need something like:

```
(str:string-case field
  ("FODL.*" (do something)))
```

(try to match the regex "FODL.*" for a field)

Comment: What's the AWK script? What does/should it do?

Comment: See https://www.cliki.net/Text (and more generally https://www.cliki.net/) for possible resources about learning Common Lisp and about libraries (sometimes outdated, but then knowing the name you can find an archive).

Comment: You'll probably need cl-ppcre for regular expressions, and a simple `cond` (instead of `case`). See also the cl-awk library: [blog post](https://lisp-journey.gitlab.io/blog/snippet-manipulating-rows-and-columns-with-clawk/).

Answer (score 4):

depending on the translated script complexity, you can use something as simple as `cond` + [ppcre](http://edicl.github.io/cl-ppcre/), or something more sophisticated, like [trivia](https://github.com/guicho271828/trivia/wiki/) pattern matching, which also has ppcre based patterns contrib:

```
(ql:quickload :cl-ppcre)
(ql:quickload :trivia)
(ql:quickload :trivia.ppcre)

(use-package '(:trivia :trivia.ppcre))

(match "other"
  ((ppcre "som[e|a].") :some)
  ((ppcre "^oth") :other))
;;=> :OTHER

(match "some"
  ((ppcre "som[e|a].") :some)
  ((ppcre "^oth") :other))
;;=> NIL

(match "something"
  ((ppcre "som[e|a].") :some)
  ((ppcre "^oth") :other))
;;=> :SOME
```

Comment: I'll try the trivia solution

Comment: Trivia is wonderful, well worth the learning curve.  Trivia is the successor/optimizer to a package known as optima (so you end up reading optima doc and such a lot).  I wrote a bit about optima almost a decade ago, which might illuminate what a power tool it is. https://enthusiasm.cozy.org/archives/2013/07/optima